# i can use Order by title in WordPress not work in WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a question. I wrote a query to the following code:

```
     <ul>
         <?php
       $current_category = get_queried_object_id();
     $query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'table_partner', // name of post type.
     'tax_query' => array(
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'table_partner_tax', // taxonomy name
             'field' => 'term_id', // term_id, slug or name
             'terms' => $current_category, // term id, term slug or term name
           'order' => 'ASC',
             'orderby' => 'title'
         )
     )
) );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>

  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a> </li>
 
  <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
    
     ?>
     </ul>
```

But it does not sort by name
I wrote a
`var_dump($query->request)`
to see what orderby is telling me
`ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12`
What should I do now to prioritize that sort with the title?

I from the code snippet

```
function remove_query_order($order) {
   remove_filter('posts_orderby','remove_query_order',PHP_INT_MAX);
   return '';
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','remove_query_order',PHP_INT_MAX);
```

I used it but it didn't work

Comment: You have the order by in the `tax_query`, it needs to be part of the main section

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed With this Code
This code uses the posts_orderby filter to modify the ORDER BY clause of the SQL query directly. It sets the orderby parameter to sort by the post title in ascending order.

```
function custom_posts_orderby( $orderby, $query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC";
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Unless you are conditionally adding this, it will run on _every_ query, just FYI